# How do check DB connection is proper [PERL]

Tags: perl

In perl how to check whether db con object is able to access data base or not ?

== when fcgi is running and db got disconnected/shutdown fcgi db con object will fail to connect to database and the error will get only while binding a query or executing a query .. How to detect dbcon obj is proper before binding or executing a query .. ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  It isn't clear what you mean by a 'db con' object.  There are many possible packages that you might be asking about — Perl DBI (Database Interface) is perhaps the best known and most comprehensive, but it is very far from being the only one.  FCGI is another rather broad topic; there is an FCGI module, but there are alternatives and extensions too.  You need to specify more precisely what you're after.  In DBI, there is a `ping` method that might be relevant.  As it stands, your question is to imprecise to be answerable.

Comment: Give a try at [DBIx::Connector](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Connector) : it caches the database connection, and provides several ways to deal with unwanted disconnections.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about a DBI connection object. All DBI handles have a `ping()` method which will check whether or not the connection is still active.

The [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#ping) says this:

> **ping**
>
> ```
> $rc = $dbh->ping;
> ```
>
> Attempts to determine, in a reasonably efficient way, if the database server is still running and the connection to it is still working. Individual drivers should implement this function in the most suitable manner for their database engine.
>
> The current default implementation always returns true without actually doing anything. Actually, it returns "0 but true" which is true but zero. That way you can tell if the return value is genuine or just the default. Drivers should override this method with one that does the right thing for their type of database.
>
> Few applications would have direct use for this method. See the specialized Apache::DBI module for one example usage.

I think that's what you want.